# Help me with my architecture - global variables in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, global-variables

I'm thinking about global variables in my rails application. I've searched the net about that, and found it (of course) flagged as a bad practice. I already knew that.

But I have not found another way than a global variable for what I need. Can an experienced Rails programmer help me ?

What I want to do is to create a new dedicated logger, for example logging to "log/audit.txt" and share it between several controllers. Of course, I would rather not have to recreate this "logger" object for every request.

For now, I create a logger in a global variable $my_logger in an initializer, and use it across my controllers.

What do you think ? Is there a better way to do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general OO stance against using global variables and singletons of any type -- in Rails and in all other OO habitats -- is to avoid the "slippery slope" towards not doing OO design at all. **Global variables are to be avoided as much as possible, but your logger is obviously a case where a Singleton of some sort makes sense.** The Rails environment is an example: you only have on Rails environment per application, and it's essentially a Singleton. Or consider `Notifier.deliver`...

Don't worry about where to put it if it must be global. Make a Singleton object with class methods as accessors and put it in `lib` or anywhere you think is appropriate (making a plugin might also be appropriate, for instance). Then you just use `Logger.instance.log whatever`. Of course you'll have to put in safeguards to make sure that the thing gets instantiated only once.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I took eventually. The "include Singleton" of Ruby made it a breeze.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, Singleton gets a bad rap, but in certain cases he's the man for the job.

Answer (score 1):

This SO question is extremely relevant: [In Ruby on Rails how can I persist objects in memory between sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354156/in-ruby-on-rails-how-can-i-persist-objects-in-memory-between-sessions)

If you use the accepted answer, you'll be able to keep the logger in memory in production mode across requests.

> However, I like the second answer...
>   to quote:
>
> I wouldn't worry too much about
>   loading and discarding objects unless
>   you can come up with a benchmark that
>   proves it's an issue. Each request
>   creates an extraordinary amount of
>   intermediate objects as a matter of
>   course, and these are generally
>   created and destroyed in a matter of
>   several milliseconds.
>
> ...
>
> Benchmark first, optimize only when
>   required.

Comment: OP's not worried about loading and discarding objects. OP is worried about opening and closing files every time he/she wants to write to a log.

Comment: @Yar: not sure how you drew that conclusion. OP said "I would rather not have to recreate this "logger" object for every request."

Comment: Thank you for this interesting link, complementing my analyzis.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom logger class and require it when applicable.

Example here:

http://ianma.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/custom-logging-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Thank you. This method means that the logger will be re-created for every request. That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Except of course if, like in your example, you include it in the environment.rb. But then it becomes a global variable/constant. Back to start...